Slowly increasing smooth mappings with values in a Lie group?
Let $G$ be $l$-dimensional compact Lie group and consider any smooth $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to G$.
Then, the first-order derivative of $F$ at each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be regarded as a linear mapping $D_x F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^l$. Let us fix a matrix norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ and assume that
\begin{equation}
x \mapsto \lVert D_x F \rVert \text{ is polynomially bounded}
\end{equation}
We can extend the above notion of polynomial boundedness to higher order derivatives as well.
Now, let us define a set $\mathfrak{G}$ as the set of $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to G$ such that $F$ is smooth and all its derivatives are polynomially bounded in the above sense.
Now, my question is that

Is this $\mathfrak{G}$ a group under pointwise multiplication and inverse?

That is,

For any $F_1, F_2 \in \mathfrak{G}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $(F_1 F_2)(x) := F_1(x) F_2(x)$. Then, do we have $F_1 F_2 \in \mathfrak{G}$?

For any $F \in \mathfrak{G}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $F^{-1}(x) := [F(x)]^{-1}$. Then, do we have $F^{-1} \in \mathfrak{G}$.


I think the item 1 must be true, but not sure about item 2. For example, can a derivative of $F$ decay exponentially at infinity, making a derivative of $F^{-1}$ "grow exponentially" at infinity?
Could anyone please clarify for me? If I am wrong about $\mathfrak{G}$ being a group, what additional conditions should I impose to make it into a group?
Add) I think this is indeed the case for $\operatorname{SU}(N)$ with $N \geq 2$ or any direct product of them. Still, I haven't figured out for general $G$.
Add 2) This ME post shows that my guess is also true for $\operatorname{U}(1)$.

Note that the maps
$$\iota: G\to G,\ x\mapsto x^{-1}\qquad \mu:G\times G\to G,\ (x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$$
have bounded derivatives, since you are assuming $G$ to be compact.
Then for $F_1, F_2\in\mathfrak G$ you have that the derivatives of
$$F_1^{-1}=\iota\circ F_1,\qquad F_1\cdot F_2 = \mu\circ (F_1,F_2)$$
will have polynomial growth, being the composition of a map whose derivative has polynomial growth and a map with bounded derivative.

I do not clearly see how we can use compactness of $G$ to show that $\iota: G\to G$ has bounded derivatives. Could you provide more details?

$d\iota: G \to \Bbb R^\ell$ is a continuous function with compact domain.

@mme I am confused about the domain and range of your differential. Are you thinking pointwise on $G$ or the whole tangent bundle?

@Isaac the norms $|d\iota|$ and $|d\mu|$ are continuous $\Bbb R$-valued functions on $G$ and $G\times G$. Compactness of $G$ guarantees that their image is bounded.

@or By $\lVert d \iota \rVert$, you mean $g \to \lVert d_g \iota \rVert$ for $g \in G$?

@or Plus, I think your argument can be generalized for higher derivatives. That is, $g \to \lVert d^n_g \iota \rVert$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Here, I have used the notation $d^n_g \iota$ for $n$-order Frechet derivative of $\iota$ evaluated at $g \in G$.

Yes, I mean that function. The argument can be applied to show the boundedness of the norms of the higher order derivatives of $\iota$ and $\mu$ as well (higher derivatives are usually described via "jets" in differential geometry).

@or I have not seen the term "jet" before. Could you explain more? I am more used to the notion of Frechet derivative, which of course should be understood locally (= on local charts) for manifolds. Well, I admit that it can be a little bit awkward for manifolds.
